# Choosing teams using a 17 word song.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We have $n$ people in a circle and a captain divides the teams by reciting a 17 word song/poem and pointing at each person with every word in a clockwise direction. When the song ends, the person the captain is pointing at is chosen for the team and *must leave the circle*. Then he starts the song again with the next person and goes through the whole song to choose the second person to join the team. This process is done over and over until half of the available people have been chosen for the first team, the other half is assigned to the second team. Counting the first person the captain points at as 1, what position (of the circle) will be chosen on the $i$-th iteration of the song?

This problem has me stumped. I have a solution which I was sure should work but hasn't.

**My solution:**

*i)* It is clear that the person in position $(17 \mod n)$ will be chosen in the first iteration.

*ii)* To find the next person, we have to start at the position right next to the one in the above iteration and count $17$ more places, skipping over the first person we have chosen (we do not count this person). To do this, since we are counting from the next person over from the first iteration, the second person would be at position:
$$
(17 \mod n) + \big[ 17 + 17//(n-1) \big] \mod n
$$

Where $x//y$ is the quotient function (the smallest whole number when $x$ is divided by $y$). The term $17//(n-1)$ is added because this is how many times we would encounter the person chosen in *i)* while going around the circle now with $n-1$ people.

*iii)* Similarly as above, we start from the position given by the previous iteration and add $17$ steps, skipping over the **two people** we have already "discarded" from the circle of $n$ people (now our circle is of n-2 people). So the new position chosen at this third iteration is:
$$
\bigg( (17 \mod n) + \big[ 17 + 17//(n-1) \big] \mod n \bigg) + \big[ 17 + 17//(n-2) \big] \mod n
$$
*iv)* At this point, I thought we could generalize the pattern into the formula below. The person chosen at iteration $i$ of the song is the person given by the following position:
$$
\bigg[ 17i + \sum_{k=1}^{i-1} 17//(n-k) \bigg] \mod n
$$
I was certain this would work and seems to do so for the first few iterations of any $n$ (keep in mind, $n$ must be even). It fails at the 3rd iteration when $n = 8$:

1. The first person chosen should be position 1. My formula agrees, as plugging in $i = 1$ gives the correct answer.
2. The second person should be position 4. My formula agrees by plugging in $i = 2$.
3. The third person should be position 2 but my formula gives 1 again.

Is there something I might be missing? Have I overcomplicated things?

Comment: This is a variation on the Josephus Problem, so you may find some useful info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem

Comment: Taking a second look at this... shouldn't your modulus also become $n-k$ each time? In your $n=8$ example, using mod $7$ would get you the $i=4$ from the formula, that you already got by actual counting. That said, I'm not sure this works for a general solution unless we specify whether each person keeps the same $i$ when someone leaves, or it the numerical gaps close up.

Comment: @EricSnyder keep in mind, the formula I'm trying to find should allow me to find the position on the initial circle of $n$ people such that it is picked on the $i$-th iteration. Therefore we would need to keep the same modulus $n$. Also, yes, the person keeps their same '$i$' when another leaves because of the same reason. That said, I will look into the Josephus problem... I honestly hadn't thought of finding a recursive formula (instead of an iterative one)

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't clear which of those you were looking for. If people keep the same $i$, I just don't see how you can get a single formula. The Josephus problem page says we have explicit formulas for counting $2$ and $3$ (-ish), but $17$? Yikes.